# Connecting ASP.NET Core App to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have created simple app using Asp.NET Core. It uses entity framework and local database. I deployed my app to Google Cloud App Engine but honestly I have no idea what to do with my database. For now I'm using local sql server 
and my appSettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "connectionStrings": {
    "smogInfoDBConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SmogInfoDB;Trusted_Connection=True",
    "hangfireConnectionString": "Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true"
  }
}
```

and it works just fine when I'm debugging and using app on my computer. I understand that I need to create an instance of SQL, but how to connect my app to that database server? How to make connection string?

Comment: And where is your database server?

Comment: I want to use Google Cloud SQL

Answer (score 5):

Your connection string to Google Cloud SQL should look like:

```
Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=DB_NAME;Uid=USER_NAME;Password=PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1):

You must Authroize your computer's public ip address on Cloud SQL to access your instance.

Follow these steps:

- https://checkip.amazonaws.com/ and obtain your PC's IP address.
- On Cloud Console, navigate to Cloud SQL instance detail -> Networking Tab -> Authorized networks (section) -> Add Network.
- Optionally, provide `Name` as something like *Kacper's PC Home*
- In the `Network*` text box which is needs a mandatory IP or CIDR format input, provide your IP adddress obtained from step 1.

*Ensure that you have a static ip. Some corporate networks has a config such that the IP changes everytime you reboot or shutdown and start your PC. In such case work with your IT team and add a CIDR range on Cloud SQL Instance.*